# Efficient algorithm for finding the in-order rank of a binary tree node

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given a binary tree (not necessarily a binary search tree) and a node in that tree, What is an efficient algorithm (in Java preferably) to find the in-order rank of that node?

An `O(n)` algorithm is possible with a traversal (either recursive or iterative). Is there a better one? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you going to be doing many such queries on the tree?  Can you construct your tree so that you store the number of children each node has?

Comment: You are looking for [order statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) variant, basically.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Actually I had thought about that kind of caching (i.e. adding children information for nodes). However, what I originally needed is a one-pass algorithm (without the assumption of storing any additional information) that is better than `O(n)`.

Comment: @amit Does the order statistics tree work for a tree that is just a simple binary tree (not a search tree)?

Comment: Yes, you want the in-order rank, thast's what order statistics trees' algorithm does. It happens that in a BST, the in-order rank is also the order statistic, and that's how it is actually used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the worst case: each node has only one left child, so the whole tree becomes a linked list.

If given a root, to calculate rank you need to access the leaf, which in this case costs `O(n)`. Thus `O(n)` in worst case is the best you can achieve without storing additional information in nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. Just for giggles, If additional information were allowed to be stored on the nodes, what sort of information would you store and what would the algorithm? I am guessing while you build the tree, on each insertion of a node, you update the ancestor nodes (up to the root) with the number of child nodes (left children and right children separately) and then later in the rank retrieval algorithm leverage this information (sum of number of left children in all the ancestors including the node itself)to make it an `O(logn)` algorithm ?

Comment: @AsifIqbal absolutely. Wikipedia link in the second comment below your question explains how.